# lois lane and xerial xenus

Tags: 16.04

While 16.04 xenial xerus uses Linux kernel 4.4:
 is it a lowlatency kernel;
 will it have one available;
 be able to use kernel 3.13.0?

[audio recording/editing related]

Answer (score 1):

It is not a low-latency kernel. On Ubuntu, low-latency kernels are available as a separate package named [`linux-lowlatency`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-lowlatency). The 3.13 kernel won't be available for 16.04.

Comment: Thank you. With your assurance, I delved into 16.04 beta-2, the lowlatency kernel is indeed present, and the drivers are compatible with AMD cpu and graphics. Smooth.

Comment: (The "Ubuntu Studio Meta Installer" seems the simplest way to locate the lowlatency kernels; which may be installed independently of any other "Studio" files or settings.)